# How do i convert two decimal dates to a real date using DATEADD

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to `compare the differences between two dates.` I have used the `datediff` function to compare the difference between, but i would like it to return the `hh:mm:ss` instead of decimal values. heres the code below.

```
    ,DATEDIFF (D,sr.Start_DATE + sr.Start_time, SR.End_DATE + sr.END_time)as [DATEdiff]

    ,CAST ((sr.End_Date + sr.End_Time) - (sr.Start_Date + sr.Start_Time) as float) AS [Decimal days]
    ,round(CAST ((sr.End_Date + sr.End_Time) - (sr.Start_Date + sr.Start_Time) as float),0,1) [Real days]


      ,CAST ((SR.END_DATE + SR.END_TIME) - (SR.START_DATE + SR.START_TIME) AS FLOAT) 

         -

    round(CAST((SR.End_Date + SR.End_Time) - (SR.START_DATE + SR.START_TIME) AS FLOAT),0,1) as [decimal HH:MM]


--- Converting the decimal hours and minutes to real hours and minutes

    --,CAST (DATEDIFF( sr.End_Date , sr.End_Time) - (sr.Start_Date + sr.Start_Time),0) as time(0))


 ,CONVERT (varchar, DATEadd(MS,12 * 1000, 0),108)
```

Any advise please.

Comment: This might help [http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.